# Coursera Query returning "SELECT list expression references trips.start_station_id which is neither grouped nor aggregated"

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to figure out the station from which the bike begins a trip most frequently. The tutorial walks through the following code:

```
WITH
  longest_used_bike AS (
SELECT 
  bikeid,
  SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration
FROM
  bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
GROUP BY
  bikeid
ORDER BY
  trip_duration DESC
LIMIT 1 
)
## find station at which the longest-used bike leaves 
most often

SELECT
  trips.start_station_id,
COUNT(*) AS trip_ct
FROM
  longest_used_bike AS longest
INNER JOIN
  `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips` AS trips
ON longest.bikeid = trips.bikeid
GROUP BY
  trips.end_station_id
ORDER BY
  trip_ct DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I am getting error: "SELECT list expression references trips.start_station_id which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [17:5]"

How should I go about fixing it and still get the expected answer for the question,"In this activity, you wrote a query with an INNER JOIN to join your temporary table with the original bikeshare_trips table. Which station ID would your query return if you used a FULL JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN?" TIA

Comment: Do you have a link to the tutorial?  It could be that there is an error in it?

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/learn/analyze-data/quiz/Ac9jc/hands-on-activity-create-temporary-tables/attempt  The code works if use MAX or MIN on trip duration, but it doesnt give expected output according to coursera

Comment: It should be either `GROUP BY trips.start_station_id` or `GROUP BY trips.start_station_id, trips.end_station_id`

Comment: @dikesh Thank you! I don't know how I messed that up